Is it possible to build boost library as shared object on ARM64 architecture?
I am trying to build boost v.1.86 on Windows 11 for ARM64 architecture in a shared library format.
These are the commands I am using currently:
.\bootstrap --with-libraries=regex

.\b2 cxxflags="-arch arm64" --link=shared --variant=release address-model=64

Unfortunately I still got lib files with x64 in the name:
libboost_regex-vc143-mt-x64-1_86.lib

According to the documentation of boost, it is possible to build to arm64.

You have to indicate the toolset (docs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html#bbv2.tasks.crosscompile)
E.g.
 b2 toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux


I haven`t mentioned that I want to build for Android on Windows. So it is a cross-compile

I figured. Look at me, pointing you at the right docs :)
